# Google cloud submit shell script running on my instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In my `Debian` instance at Google Cloud, I want to know if there is a scheduler so that I can submit my shell script to run my program in my instance without having to keep the terminal open all the time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple tools that can do the job, depending on your exact use-case.

If you have a single shell-script or command that you need to leave running, the tool you're after is called [screen](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acuy).

If your script provides a service (e.g. web-server), you should daemonise it. There are various tools to help you depending on your application platform and OS version, among them [Systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), [Sysvinit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SysVinit), [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/), etc.

If you need to run the task repeatedly, use [cron](https://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/).

All tools are OS-based and are independent of hosting platform.

Comment: Thank you so much. Never known about them before. Very helpful